# How to Use $watch here so the API is triggered before the Directive- USING ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

EDIT->I am also using a ui-router- Can i use resolve
 name: 'PLANSPONSOR.SUMMARY',

```
  state: {
     url: "/summary",
     templateUrl: '../script/planSummary.html',
     controller: "summaryCtrl",params:{obj:null}
    }
 }
]
```

I am trying to trigger the API before the directive in my controller. 
The Directive needs my API to be called to get the data so that it can populate on the page.

When i load the page the directive fires because its called in HTML and the API is triggered next. 
Can anybody help me on Using the $watch function or do i need to use something else so that API is triggered on the page and then Directive.

API CODE (trimmed for code sanity)

```
$timeout(function () {$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'getPSDetails?psuid='+$scope.psuId,
      //url: 'getPSDetails?controlNumber='+$scope.DataEntered,
        }).success(function (data) {
         console.log('success response');   }

$scope.summaryObject =data; ( I am getting all the data here )
```

My Directive. (trimmed for code sanity)

```
myapp.directive('summaryFeatureDetails',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:true,
        controller:function($scope){

            $scope.columnPerPage = 5;
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            $scope.currentColumns = [];
            $scope.controlData = [];
            $scope.totalNumberOfPage = Math.floor($scope.selectedData.length/$scope.columnPerPage);
            if (($scope.selectedData.length % $scope.columnPerPage) > 0){
                $scope.totalNumberOfPage = $scope.totalNumberOfPage + 1;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use binding with your directive and pass the data through the controller instead of using global scope. No need of $watch.

Comment: Oups, I didn't see the controller in the directive. But why you are calling the API outside the directive? Is it call in a controller ($timeout)?

Comment: I want the api to trigger when the page loads because there are other parts of the page which are not directive dependent.

Comment: When the api is trigged? app.run / app.controller?

Comment: when the page load. The directive is triggerd first then API. 
I want the other way round

Answer (score 1):

If the directive loads before the `$scope.summaryObject` is set then make sure to load the directive **after** the object is set.
This can be done by simply adding an [NgIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) expression on the directive tag which checks the object value and only render the html if the object is not null

```
<yourDirectiveTag ng-if="!summaryObject" ></yourDirectiveTag>
```

Comment: I am using directive for diffrerent set of pages like this. 
I can't put Ng-if.


myapp.directive('summaryCategoryList',function(){
 return {
  restrict:'E',
  templateUrl:'../script/planSummaryCategoryList.html'
 }
});

Comment: @InsaneFragger please share the complete code then. The controller which loads the api and the view that loads the diretive

Answer (score 0):

I will try an answer to help you with what I see. This is how I do my stuff:

Controller:

```
var vm = this;
vm.dataToDisplay = [];
...    
$http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'getPSDetails?psuid='+$scope.psuId,          
}).success(function (data) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(vm.dataToDisplay, data);   
}
```

Directive:

```
myapp.directive('summaryFeatureDetails',function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myData: '='
        }
        /* No controller */
```

HTML:

```
<summary-feature-details my-data="vm.dataToDisplay"></summary-feature-details>
```